# Cannot load a saved video file using unitys video player. File gets removed

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, unity-game-engine

I am downloading a .webm video from our server and store it in Application.persistentDataPath. When loading this video, the video is not played and the file gets removed on both android and iOS. I am using Unity 2018.2.8f1

Streaming the video using http works fine, and I have also tried downloading the video on a computer and placing it in the persistent data path manually, which works fine as well. It seems that this problem only occurs when the video is downloaded during runtime, which leads me to believe that I am saving the video file inccorectly. If I just download the video inside the app, and copy it to my pc, the video plays fine. I have tried giving the app different read/write permissions, but there's no change in behavior.

Here is the code to save the file.

```cs
IEnumerator DownloadVideo(int id, Image loadBar)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://*Server url*" + id + ".webm");
        www.SendWebRequest();

        while(!www.isDone)
        {
            loadBar.fillAmount = www.downloadProgress;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            using (FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/video" + id + ".webm", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                file.Write(www.downloadHandler.data, 0, www.downloadHandler.data.Length);
                file.Flush();
                file.Close();
                file.Dispose();
            }

            Debug.Log("Saved successfully!");
        }
    }
```

And this is how I load the video

```cs
if (FileExists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/video" + GlobalConfig.id + ".webm"))
            {
                video.SetPath(Application.persistentDataPath + "/video" + GlobalConfig.id + ".webm");
                Debug.Log("Load Locally");
            }
/*
...
*/
            video.Prepare();
```

(I use a third party video player for android, Universal Media Player, and created an adapter for the video players in case the method names are confusing)

I get no error messages, but I do see that the video files gets removed. The expected behavior is to play the video file, and not have it deleted from storage. I have tried giving the file different read/write accesses for both FileAccess and FileSharing.

This is my first post here, so I hope I have included all necessary information. Otherwise please let me know if I forgot something important.

Comment: I had an issue working with assets that forced me to save the file on retrieval before I could instantiate it as a GameObject. Troubleshotting this I found a lot of issues that I overcame. In my scenario I had to change the filetype uploaded to BINARY. aswell options such as UnityWebRequestMultimedia is also available in ur case. If neither of these helps you, tell me and Ill dig further into it

Comment: Thank you for the response! Using UnityWebRequestMultimedia is not a solution in my case. I am not quite sure what you mean by changing the file type to binary? I am not using assetbundles, but rather raw webm videos. I save the bytes that I download directly, as these should already be encoded for webm.

Comment: Just to be sure. Do the video get removed on load, or when is this?

Comment: Yes, as soon as video.Prepare() is called, the video file is removed from the drive. Before that, I can still see the video in the file manager (I can also play the video with androids default video player outside of my app)